# I get the right print but I still receive an error (codecademy, python, lists and dictionaries, 8/13)

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am progressing through Codecademy's python lessons and I'm stuck with an error at the 8/13 part of the lists and dictionaries section, titled "a day at the supermarket".

The lesson wants me to print out individual produces and their corresponding prices and stock. This is what I wrote:

```
prices = {
    "banana" : 4,
    "apple" : 2,
    "orange" : 1.5,
    "pear" : 3
    }

stock = {
    "banana" : 6,
    "apple" : 0,
    "orange" : 32,
    "pear" : 15
    }

for key in prices:
    print key
    print "Price: %s" % prices[key]
    print "Stock: %s" % stock[key]
    print
```

I get the following print:

```
orange
Price: 1.5
Stock: 32

pear
Price: 3
Stock: 15

banana
Price: 4
Stock: 6

apple
Price: 2
Stock: 0
```

And the following error message:

"Oops, try again. Check what your code prints for orange. It doesn't look quite right!"

It seems fine to me...
What am I missing here?

Comment: the discussion section has the answer and its quite weird.Faced the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the coding exercise expects the case of the first letter on each line to be lower-case.

Also, maybe no empty newline between fruits?

Comment: Thank you, writing in lower-case solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can see potentially wrong with this is the fact that you use %s to print out a number when really you should be using %d instead.

Check out they python docs on string formatting.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Other than this, I cannot see anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
prices = {"banana": 4, "apple": 2, "orange": 1.5, "pear": 3}
stock = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32, "pear": 15}
for i in prices and stock:
print i
print "price: " + str(prices[i])
print "stock: " + str(stock[i])
```

paste this code, it works

Answer (score 0):

I removed the 's' from prices, which fixed the issue.